# Latest commit hash of subdirectory

Tags: git

I need to check latest changes in a subdirectory of a git repo. I would like to get the latest commit info in one line (sha, author, message, and may be date). Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git log -n 1 --format="%h %aN %s %ad" -- $directory
```

Comment: and add `-n 1` to only show the latest commit. For safety, in case you have any tags or branches that are named the same as the dir, place `--` before `$directory`

Comment: @jbowes: yes, thanks. I'm lazy, so I usually just use `| head 1` to get only the first line :)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can advice me how to list branches with latest commit date. This seems not possible with `git branch -av ...` EDIT: and remote branches as well!

Comment: Ok, found a way `git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/ --format='%(refname) %(committerdate) %(authorname)'`

Comment: It's just colors missing, but I better open another question for branch list.